# Entity Framework - Inheritance - Zero to one Relationship to child object, how to map? (Fluent API)

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship, fluent-interface

I have a Inheritance Hierarchy where Action is parent of ActionCompleted and ActionCancelled. Order class has a zero to one ActionCompleted and ActionCancelled. I have tried TPH and TPT (even tried edmx) but unable to get Entity to understand this relationship between Order and child actions, please suggest how do I map?

```
//Classes
    public class Order
    {
        public   int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public   ActionCompleted ACO { get; set; }
        public ActionCancelled ACA { get; set; }

    }

public class Action
{
    public   int ActionID { get; set; }
    public   DateTime ActionDT { get; set; }
    public   Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class ActionCompleted : Action
{

}
public class ActionCancelled : Action
{
    public int CancelledByPhysician { get; set; }
}
```

//Mappings

```
public class EDISContext:DbContext
{
    public EDISContext()
        : base("EDISContext")
    { }


    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Action> Actions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().ToTable("Orders");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Action>().HasKey(a => a.ActionID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Action>().Map(m => m.ToTable("Actions"))
                                              .Map<ActionCompleted>(m => m.ToTable("ActionCompleted"))
                                              .Map<ActionCancelled>(m => m.ToTable("ActionCancelled"));

        //modelBuilder.Entity<Action>().HasRequired(a => a.Order).WithOptional().Map(m => m.MapKey("DiagOrderId"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<ActionCompleted>().HasRequired(a => a.Order).WithOptional().Map(m => m.MapKey("DiagOrderId"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<ActionCancelled>().HasRequired(a => a.Order).WithOptional().Map(m => m.MapKey("DiagOrderId"));

    }
```

### }

Code used to save data:

```
EDISContext db = new EDISContext();
var ord1 = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderId == 1);
ActionCompleted ac= new ActionCompleted();
ac.ActionDT = DateTime.Now;
ac.Order = ord1;
db.Actions.Add(ac);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Script of DB tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actions](
    [ActionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActionDT] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DiagOrderID] [int] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActionCompleted](
    [ACID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActionID] [int] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActionCancelled](
    [ACAID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CancelledByPhysician] [int] NULL,
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: I know I am getting impatient but I am wondering if Entity Framework is being used at all? May be I need to start looking at Nhibernate.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "unable to get Entity to understand this relationship between Order and child actions"?  If you create orders and actions and try to save them to the database, what happens?  I copied and pasted your code to a console application and it worked fine.

Comment: I think it throws the exception similar to below:Invalid column name 'ActionCompleted_ActionId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'ActionCompleted_ActionId
----
Just to be clear Orders table is related to Actions table, with OrderId stored in Action table as a foreign key. (no reference key present in orders table, is that how you created your tables?)
----
If you do not mind can you please post the script of the tables you have created, I will try my code again. I will post the script of my tables shortly.

Comment: Another thing: I am using an existing order while adding actions, I set their order property, see below:

    EDISContext db = new EDISContext(); 
    var ord1 = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderId == 1); 
    OrderActionEntered ae1 = new OrderActionEntered(); 
    ae1.ActionDoneBy=1;
    ae1.ActionDT =DateTime.Now; 
    ae1.Order = ord1;
    db.OrderActions.Add(ae1);
    db.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 1):

When using code first, it's always useful to at least try letting EF create the database for you - this is the default behavior (will look for local instance of SQL Server called .\SQLEXPRESS).  If you create the database manually and want to control the column names, which is what seems like is happening, you'll need to specify the column name with the fluent API.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295845(v=vs.103).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295847(v=VS.103).aspx for some examples that should cover what you're getting stuck on.

Just for reference, the database you've created would have the following tables and column names:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActionCancelled](
    [ActionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CancelledByPhysician] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ActionID] ASC )
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActionCompleted](
    [ActionID] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ActionID] ASC )
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actions](
    [ActionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActionDT] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Order_OrderId] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ActionID] ASC )
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ACO_ActionID] [int] NULL,
    [ACA_ActionID] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [OrderId] ASC )
)
```

Comment: I do not understand why I need to give those columns. Those properties are accessed by going to the Actions table and joining to the ActionCompleted if I am looking for the ActionCompleted property. I even tried the TPH mapping and there also it did not work, same error. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276175/entity-framework-fluent-api-table-per-hierarchy-exception)

Comment: All the examples I have seen end up relationship with the parent class in some form of collection property. But to me the solution i am looking for looks natural and it is so easy to implement using custom database coding. Now I am going to try with Nhibernate and see if I will have some luck there. Why should I store the OrderId in the action tables as a reference key when I will have the ActionId in the orders table, seems like bidirectional relationship of the object world is being pushed into the relational world.

Comment: On second look my database script does not look wrong. it has redundant unique ids in each table. Where ever the column name is not same as the property name I have used fluent api to indicate the same. I will try to test this code again without the order to see if it still works.

Comment: What If i have 15 properties of type action in order class. and Order is supposed to have zero to one of them, I know I can use a collection of actions to fetch from the DB and write some logic in the getter to get these individual properties.

Comment: Not sure I understand all of your questions.  Re: why should you store the OrderId in the action tables; you wouldn't *have* to but if you don't you will need an index on the *ActionId columns in Orders or you will be doing a table scan to find the Order for a given Action.  Re: 15 properties; in that case Order would have 15 nullable *ActionId columns.  There are certainly other valid schema representations of the same, but the algorithms for defining database schemas are pretty well tested.  The database EF would generate would perform similarly to any of the alternatives I can identify.

Comment: 15 nullable columns is fine with you, instead of a foreign key which has been done since ages. And you think EF is a great schema generator??

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on creating and maintaining the database yourself, I advise you to try using the Database First workflow, not Code First. Create an Entity Data Model from your database then generate the POCOs. It will make your life much easier, especially in the case you change your database schema.

As for the EDM to understand table relationships, you must set them in the database. I don't know if you alread did it since you haven't pasted any script that creates the foreign keys but VS should not have any problems understanding propperly defined schemas.

Comment: I want to create my POCOS and DB also seperately and then map them using the ORM. But I will try to do DB first and see if the proper POCOS get created. BTW I could not get an answer to this issue even from Nhibernate in my other post.