# Nhibernate - Inheritance - Zero to one Relationship to child object, how to map? (Fluent API)

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance

I have a Inheritance Hierarchy where Action is parent of ActionCompleted and ActionCancelled. Order class has a zero to one ActionCompleted and ActionCancelled.

the only place I wanted to keep the foreign key is in the action table of the orderId. is that possible? This works fine in the relational world?? There maybe 7-8 ActionTypes and order will have zero to one relationship to all of them.

I am new to ORM and started with EF but so far did not get any help to resolve this issue, now I want to explore this using NHibernate. I know it maybe too much to ask but if anyone has some free time and can write me the mappings for the below scenario it will be appreciated. If you can point me to some sample which uses similar scenario that will be also great help. Since I am just getting started with Nhibernate it may be too much for me to take on inheritance mapping and mapping to the child object.

Below is the link to the code for classes and the DB script, please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks.

[Entity Framework - Inheritance - Zero to one Relationship to child object, how to map? (Fluent API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286366/entity-framework-inheritance-zero-to-one-relationship-to-child-object-how-t)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/69d9145a-f7ec-4845-b01a-26e57e9ba16e?prof=required

Answer (score 2):

```
//Classes
public class Order
{
    public virtual int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ActionCompleted ACO { get; set; }
    public virtual ActionCancelled ACA { get; set; }

}

public class Action
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ActionDT { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class ActionCompleted : Action
{

}
public class ActionCancelled : Action
{
    public Physician CancelledBy { get; set; }
}

// FluentNHibernate Mappings
public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.OrderId);

        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.ACO, "ActionCompletedId");
        References(x => x.ACA, "ActionCanceledId");
    }
}

public class ActionMap : ClassMap<Action>
{
    public ActionMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ActionID);
        DiscriminateSubclassOn("ActionType");   // if present TPH, otherwise TPC

        Map(x => x.ActionDT);
        References(x => x.Order, "DiagOrderId");
    }
}

public class ActionCompletedMap : SubclassMap<ActionCompleted>
{
    public ActionCompletedMap()
    {
        DiscrimitatorValue("Completed");
    }
}
public class ActionCancelledMap : SubclassMap<>
{
    public ActionCompletedMap()
    {
        DiscrimitatorValue("Completed");
        Refernces(x => x.CancelledBy, "CancelledByPhysician");
    }
}

// factory aka ObjectContext
ISessionFactory factory = Fluently.Configure()
    .DataBase(SqlServerConfiguration.Standard.Connectionstring(connstring))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<OrderMap>())
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Update: Update 2:

```
// FluentNHibernate Mappings
public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.OrderId);

        Map(x => x.Name);

        Join("ActionTable", join => 
        {
            .KeyColumn("OrderId");
            join.Optional();
            join.Where("ActionType = 'ActionCompleted'");
            join.Component(x => x.ACO, c => 
            {
                c.Map(x => x.ActionID).Not.Insert();
                c.Map(x => x.ActionDT);
                c.ParentReference(x => x.Order);
            }
        }));
        Join("ActionTable", join =>
        {
            join.KeyColumn("OrderId");
            join.Optional();
            join.Where("ActionType = 'ActionCanceled'");
            join.Component(x => x.ACA, c => 
            {
                c.Map(x => x.ActionID).Not.Insert();
                c.Map(x => x.ActionDT);
                c.ParentReference(x => x.Order);
                c.Map(x => x.CanceledBy);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, if you do not mind what versuion of NHibernate shall I try above code with?

Comment: FluentNHibernate 1.1(with NH2.1) or FLuentNhibernate 1.2(with NH 3.1)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Since you are so generous, I wanted to ask you for some more :) . I have been searching the internet for some quick start solution using Nhibernate, which will write to the DB, using SQL Server but could not find any yet. I found some which use XML mapping though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the db is not that important, it is abstracted away through NH. Examples: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/tree/master/src/Examples.FirstProject http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200912NHibernate/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3498

Comment: Sorry Firo, when I examined your code in detail, seems like you have the ActionCompletedId and ActionCancelledId in the order table, which is not what I wanted. This was the same solution being suggested using Entity Framework. Order will have zero to one actionCompleted and other action types, and the only place I wanted to keep the foreign key is in the action table of the orderId. is that possible? This works fine in the relational world??

Comment: I am getting various errors, about the KeyColumn, where etc ----Error FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ComponentPart does not contain a definition for 'KeyColumn' and no extension method 'KeyColumn' accepting a first argument of type-----both with fluentNH1.1(NH2.1) and FNH1.2(with NH3.1)

Comment: @krprasad sorry for the mistakes. i wrote it from memory without compiler. KeyColumn and Optional are part of the join and not the Component

Comment: Sorry still too many issues. join.Where does not exist, "c.Map(x => x.ActionId).NotInsert()" // NotInsert also does not exist.

Comment: Sorry still not working. I got this error -{"Tried to add join to table 'Action' when already added."}. Hence, I removed the second join (for ActionType ="ActionCancelled") and then I tired to save the one which was mapped (for Action ActionType = "ActionCompleted").It did save Action this time but did not save the OrderId.